# Working with JS objects and functions

Tags: javascript, function, object

I'm a newbie in javascript and I'm wondering why `bob.age` is still 30 while `age` is 50 when I called it. I already set `age` to 50 in `setAge` that assigned 50 to `this.age`, which I know is a reference to `bob.age`, so `age` and `bob.age` should have the same value.

[image]

```
// here we define our method using "this", before we even introduce bob
var setAge = function (newAge) {
    this.age = newAge;
};
// now we make bob
var bob = new Object();
bob.age = 30;
// and down here we just use the method we already made

// change bob's age to 50 here
bob.setAge = setAge(50);
```

Comment: Please include the code in the question itself, not just an image, so it's easier for people to copy in their answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> bob.setAge = setAge(50);

all that is doing is setting the setAge property of bob to the result of calling setAge(50) - as setAge retunrs undefined, you've effectively set bob.SetAge = undefined. Perhaps what you intended to do was

```
bob.setAge = setAge; 
bob.setAge(50);
```

untested, but I think it's right

Comment: Wait why do you need to assign setAge to bob.setAge?

Comment: you mean the other way around, assign bob.setAge to setAge - see ChadF's more complete answer for an explanation

Answer (score 7):

There're several errors in your code/understanding, I'm going to start with why that is specifically wrong, and explain the concepts around it

`var bob = new Object()` is making bob a regular object.

your `setAge` function takes in a parameter.  It sets `this.age` to be that value.  However setAge is placed on the global scope.  Therefore `this` -> `window`.  Which is why when your typed in `age` in the global scope you got 50.

Jaromanda is correct, you need to place the function `setAge` onto the object bob.

If you're playing around with `this` you may be interested in the pseudoclassical instantiation style:

```
var Person = function(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.setAge = function(newAge) {
    this.age = newAge;
}

var bob = new Person ('Bob', 30);
bob.setAge(50);
bob.age; 
// 50
```

Comment: The `->` is likely misleading to newbies. I recommend changing it to a standard `// comment`

Comment: this makes me more confused

Comment: @user3783598: at what point did I lose you?  Did the first half make sense?  Through to the point that I said Jaromanda was right?  Pseudoclassical is another thing, which you probably shouldn't worry about now, but I'd be happy to clarify/explain further.

Comment: I just don't get the prototype thing in the sample you've made but the rest is fine. Anyways I already understood it. Thanks

Comment: Person.prototype is an object you can attach functions to.  Any `Person` will have access to all the functions on `prototype`.  So even though `bob` technically only has `name` and `age` properties, he can access the functions attached to the prototype because he is a `Person`

Answer (score 1):

The keyword **this** acts as a placeholder, and will *refer to whichever object called that method* when the method is actually used.

Look at the method setAge to see how this works. By using the keyword **this**, *setAge* will change the age property of any object that calls it.

Then when we say **bob.setAge = setAge**; it means whenever we type **bob.setAge( )** *this.age* in the *setAge* method will refer to **bob.age.**

Comment: I think you're just confused with bob.setAge which is a property of bob and setAge which is a function. So when you assign bob.setAge to setAge it means bob.setAge is defined by setAge and can access the setAgefunction by passing a value to parameter. bob.setAge(20);